# Selenium IDE Issue In Export Result

Tags: selenium

I have created one function in .JS file, using which I calculate the response time of login functionality, it's working fine, the log is also showing the response time correctly. But when I am exporting the Test result and open it in Firefox, its showing me all the steps as pass but not showing the calculated time. Its only showing the variable in which I store the calculated time not its value whereas the log is displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

You should print the calculated result by using echo command.The variable which is printed by echo function must be like this format:

Command = echo,
Target = ${printedVal}